# Showing Custom Page of Portlet as Liferay start up

Tags: liferay-6

Inside my Liferay Tomcat Bundle Web-apps folder , i have deployed a Liferay-Struts2 Portlet , and its working fine

My Portlet name is RaviPortlet and 
This is the path under it as shown

```
E:\liferaytomcat\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\tomcat-7.0.22\webapps\RaviPortlet-portlet
```

Please see the contents under my RaviPortlet-portlet in this screen shot

[image]

I want to show this default Landing Page as CustomLogin.jsp under RaviPortlet-portlet.
So inside portal-ext.properties file i have modified it to

default.landing.page.path=/RaviPortlet-portlet/CustomLogin.jrtup sp

But i am getting Error under Server Console 
Please tell me if this is correct ?? and if not how is that we show our cutom page on Liferay start up

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a portlet as a landing page. You must put your portlet on a page, and then have that page as a landing page. 
It seems you are trying to make a login-portlet ? It will therefore be natural to put it on an public-page that everyone has access to. 
Hope I have understood you right and that this is was of any help to you.

Armaz

Comment: Hi Zamra , Thanks for the reply ,  You must put your portlet on a page . Could you please tell me what does this exactly mean ??

Comment: Hi. I mean adding your portlet on a page. You know, using the "Add" button on menu on the top dockbar, finding your portlet and adding it to the (current) page. You surly must have done this, otherwise you wouldn’t know your portlet works.

Comment: Thanks Zamra , i got your point , now my question is how can i have this particular page as the Landing page ?? My page is  CustomLogin.jsp under RaviPortlet-portlet which is under Tomcat Webapps  folder .

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing Liferay pages with portlets on them and jsp pages inside a portlet.

In general you wouldn't invoke your custom login jsp page for a number of reasons.

You would want your custom login to be a portlet so that you are operating within the Portal's session/scope.

Do this.
1.  modify your login in process to operate as portlet if it doesn't already
2.  create a public page in liferay and add the ravi portlet to it and copy the path of that page.
3.  set the default path to this page
4.  you will likely also want to modify one the portal properties where you can override the default login portlet as well.

Good luck.